# JavaScript Accessing a value from an object

Tags: javascript

When i do `console.log(data)` on a particular script that i'm using, i get the following

```
[Object {
    name = "videobody", value = "asdasd"
},
Object {
    name = "IMUFiles[]", value = "selected_arrow1327549445.png"
},
Object {
    name = "filename", value = "testing"
},
Object {
    name = "allow_comments", value = "y"
}]
```

How can i access `selected_arrow1327549445.png` from `data`

Comment: Are you looking for more than `data[1].value`?

Comment: kinda sad when an answer isn't long enough to pass validation...

Comment: Accessing it directly would be data[1].value or are you wanting to dynamically find it based on something else?

Comment: order of the objects can change. I'm just looking to grab the filename which in this example is located in the second object

Comment: How does this structure get assigned to variable. It's invalid Js according to JsLint. Doesn't run : http://jsfiddle.net/kFQE6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an array of `Object`s each with a `name` and `value` property, so:

```
data [1].value
```

EDIT: Well, since you said the order can change, maybe just loop through:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++ i)
{
    if (data [i].name === "IMUFiles[]")
    {
        alert (data [i].value); 
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not necessarily in this particular order. Order of the objects can change.

Comment: @Pinkie Do you mean you want to search that value?

Comment: So you want to traverse or search the structure?

Comment: Yes, that's just the way it's logged to the console.

Comment: @gideon yes you're right, it's doesn't validate. This is how i got it from console. I too wonder what is wrong with the code and how to make it work in jsfiddle

Comment: It's not meant to be valid, it's just a representation of it for logging purposes.